# Mongoose aggregate query with Date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose model of

```
{
  locationId: "aaaa1",
  information: [
   {
     name: "aa",
     date: "2020-09-29T19:21:57.343+00:00",
   },
   {
     name: "aa13",
     date: "2020-08-28T19:13:57.343+00:00",
   },
   {
     name: "aa141",
     date: "2020-09-29T19:20:57.343+00:00",
   }
  ]
}
```

Trying to get information objects with a selected time period.

```
const c = '2020-09-28T19:21:57.343+00:00';
info.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            locationId: 'aaaa1',
          },
          {
            $gte: ["$information.date", c],
          },
          {
            $lt: ["$information.date", Date()],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

With this, I can retrieve the info's information within the given dates. It does not return the information array. How can I get the array of the location's information array between the selected date?

Comment: Try using `new Date()` in the $lt test.